# iOS application only show Emoji & English keyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

iOS application written in Objective-C only show English & Emoji keyboards.
All other application are working normally and other keyboards (ex: Polish, Hebrew) are available to use.

I tried to look for .plist restrictions or something i did in the development process. didn't find anything.

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found the problem.
In my main.m file i had this two rows that prevent my system from allowing any other keyboard then english:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en_EN", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate
```

To overwrite this code for users who already installed the applkaction - i have changed it to:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate
}
```

Now everything is working as expected.